# Finding interecept of equation using regular expressions

Tags: regex

```
Lines=["1x+1y+0","1x-1y+0","-1ax+0y-3","0x+1y-0.5"]
```

I am trying to find the intercept, say for equation no 3 i.e "-1ax+0y-3"

```
re.findall('[+-][\w]*[^XxYy]',Lines[2])
```

but it gives me

```
['-1ax+', '-3']
```

I was expecting only `-3`

Comment: In the general case here you might need to write an expression parser.  Regex can't do math, it can only extract things.

Comment: I just want to extract the intercept here. No math stuff

Comment: Like this? `(?<=[xyXY])[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` https://regex101.com/r/enDp4h/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[+-]?\w*?[^XxYy](?=\+|-|$)` will give you the expected result.

`[+-]?` is making the sign optional, so you can also match a positive value at the start of your string

`*?` is making it ungreedy and

`(?=\+|-|$)` is a lookahead to check if there is either +, - or the end of the string after your value.

If you just want to match numbers: `[+-]?[0-9\.]+?[^XxYy](?=\+|-|$)`

`[0-9\.]` will match numbers or a decimal point!

Comment: [\w] : Can this be just this: \w

Comment: If the intercept is 0.5 then it doesnt match.
I tried intercept = re.findall(r'([+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)(?![xy])',line) # Intercept.
It gives result like this ('-0.5', '0.')

Comment: @AmolGupta Try my second RegEx! It will match the decimal point as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
(?<=[xyXY])[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=[xyXY])` Positive lookbehind, assert x or y at the left
- `[+-]?` Optionally match `+` or `-`
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match digits with an optional decimal part
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/enDp4h/1)

```
import re

Lines = ["1x+1y+0","1x-1y+0","-1ax+0y-3","0x+1y-0.5"]
print(re.findall('(?<=[xyXY])[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$', Lines[2]))
```

Output

```
['-3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'-?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b', Lines[2])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3VJ0VN/1). Details:

- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `\b` - a word boundary, no glued letters allowed
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional fractional part
- `\b` - a word boundary.